# Pointcut expression to get the argument and annotation value

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I have a pointcut expression that invokes all methods in a package.

Some methods may have annotations and a parameter that needs to get in advice.

I tried with something like this

```
@Around("execution(* com.man.test..jmx..*(..)) && args(name,..) && @annotation( requiredJMX )")
```

The problem with this expression is that it will invoke if a parameter with name and annotation exists.

Is it possible for me to invoke all methods in the package and at the same time the name parameter and annotation are optional?

Something like this

```
@Around("execution(* com.man.test..jmx..*(..)) || args(name,..) || @annotation( requiredJMX )")
```

Comment: is the second expression not what you want?

Comment: I need second expression , but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of annotation and args from method,
You can just do like this:

`@Around("execution(* com.man.test..jmx..*(..))
public Object yourMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinpoint){`

```
MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
Method method = signature.getMethod();
MyAnnotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
if(null != annotation && method.getParameters().length > 0 
     && "name".equals(method.getParameters()[0].getName())){

    //do your work
}
```

}

Comment: "name".equals(method.getParameters()[i].getName() dosent match

Comment: Is that parameter annotated with some annotation? Please share the method definition if possible. Because, If it is annotated then it will not work.

Comment: Yes this has a custom Annotation

Comment: If parameter is annotated, then you can use `method.getParameterAnnotations()` to get the name of parameter.

Comment: Sorry, only the method is annotated, not the parameter